# Move save from Xenia Canary to Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, emulation

I have been playing Forza Horizon on my PC using the Xenia Canary emulator. I recently added a modchip to my Xbox 360 and would like to transfer the save from Xenia to the Xbox. Is this possible and if so, what are the steps that I need to take?